# PHP file won't pull through 'AMOUNT' from HTML PayPal form

Tags: php, html, forms, paypal, checkout

This is my first question on SO!

I'm having issues creating a working PayPal checkout, consisting of a PHP file and HTML file (the original code is much longer but I have boiled it down and simplified it here). When triggered, the PHP file sends an email to me with the order details, before directing the customer to checkout. This works perfectly apart from the fact that the AMOUNT just doesn't seem to want to pull through to the PHP file.

The HTML file simply has string inputs for each field (Item Name, Amount, etc.):

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<form name="contactform" id="contactform" action="test.php" method="post" style="float:initial" >

<input type="hidden" id="cmd" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" id="business" name="business" value="test@test.com">
<input type="hidden" id="item_name" name="item_name" value="Test Item">
<input type="hidden" id="currency_code" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" id="amount" name="amount" value="1.00">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" id="button" style="margin-top:30px"  name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!" >

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The PHP file then puts this data into an array which it then sends on to PayPal:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['item_name'])) {


 $query_data = array(
'amount' => $_POST['amount'],
    'business' => 'test@test.com',
    'cmd' => '_xclick',     
    'currency_code' => 'USD',
    'item_name' => $_POST['item_name'],

);

}

header('Location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' . http_build_query($query_data));
exit;

?>
```

This pulls everything else including the item_name, so I'm completely stumped as to why it's not working for 'amount'.

If anyone has any ideas I'd be very grateful!

Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing I can see in this form that would prevent `amount` from being passed through the form. However, I would just like to say that you should never rely on the amount of anything being posted somewhere unless it is some sort of free-form "pay what you like" field. That sort of logic should all be handled server side. Just because the form field is hidden, doesn't mean that someone can't change the value.

Comment: According to the PayPal developer guide (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/) the form must be sent using a POST (not GET): "Important: Do not change these values. These attributes are required for all payment buttons and the Cart Upload command."  I'd be more curious why ANY of the fields are appearing correctly.  You may want to try a POST.  I don't see any other problems in the code.

Comment: for a test   put print_r($_POST);  near the top of your PHP file to find if $_POST['amount'] is even passed, or if it's just empty   ps.. follow that with die(); else your redirect will prevent you from seeing it

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies. I tried printing and everything appears as it should. So that must surely mean there is an issue with the data transferring to PayPal? And that's some good advice on the server-side issue. I shall bare that in mind

Answer (score 0):

The call to the header function at the bottom of test.php is missing a question mark between the URL and the query string.

The PHP manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) doesn't explicitly say whether the return value of the http_build_query function includes the question mark, but the examples show that it doesn't.

Since the 'amount' variable is the first one listed, it's possible it is not registering with whatever code is parsing the query string at PayPal, yet the other name-value pairs are being read since the ampersand is delimiting them.  The HTML Variables documentation for PayPal does state that the user will be prompted for an amount if one is not sent.